# reading log file sys_trace.log and printing the data into servlet out of memory error

Tags: java

```
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
for (int len; (len = fis.read(buf)) > 0 || tail;)
{
        if (len > 0) {
                os.write(buf, 0, len);
                os.flush();
                response.flushBuffer();
        } else {
                os.write('.');
                try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
                        
        os.flush();
}
```

while printing the large log file into servlet getting not enough heap memory error.

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]? I'd also not swallow any exceptions, generally.